# Javascript: Aba mestre

Tags: javascript, session, localstorage

Preciso de uma certa função em um projeto, preciso que algumas funções só executem em uma aba do meu site, por exemplo... O usuário está na aba `HOME` mas as abas `SOBRE`, `CONTATO` estão abertas e nesse site reproduz um áudio dependo do que retorno de uma consulta em um `PHP`. Então não quero todas as abas fazendo essa mesma pesquisa (que efetuo de +/- de 3 em 3 segundos), e não quero reproduzir o áudio em todas as abas (não terão nesse site somente essas páginas), então criei uma função utilizando o sessionStorage e o localStorage, segue:

```
    var app = {};

app.getTime = function()
{
    // retornar em segundos
    return new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0,10);
};

if( !sessionStorage['window']) sessionStorage['window'] = Math.floor(Math.random()*(9999999999999999-1111111111111111+1)+1111111111111111);

(app.fn = function()
{

    // Se não tiver setado o localStorage['time'] a menos de 3 sec
    // esta será a janela mestre.
    if( !localStorage['window'] || parseInt(localStorage['time'])<(app.getTime()-3))
    {

        localStorage['window'] = sessionStorage['window'];
    }

    app.mestre = (sessionStorage['window'] == localStorage['window']);

    if( app.mestre)
    {

        localStorage['time'] = app.getTime();
    }

    clearInterval(app.time);

    app.time = setInterval(function(){ app.fn(); }, 1000);

})();

///////////////

// EXEMPLO... Só a janela mestre fará a contagem...

var cont = 1;

setInterval(function(){

    if( app.mestre) document.body.innerHTML += cont++ + '  ';

}, 1000);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGujS/)** (Abra pelo menos duas vezes clicando no link - Duplicar a Aba não funciona)

O que acontece é que quando duplico a Aba como disse o sessionStorage das abas são iguais, ou seja, dá errado...

Como resolver e o que posso fazer para melhorar o código ?

Answer (score 1):

Se a mudança de aba é feita via ajax, guarde o nome da aba atual em uma variável global no ato da mudança.

```
aba = "Home";
```

ou

```
aba = "Contato";
```

Então, dentro do setInterval:

```
setInterval(function(){

    if(aba != "Home"){

        return; //se não for a aba home, sai da função antes de executar o cálculo.

    }

    if( app.mestre) document.body.innerHTML += cont++ + '  ';

}, 1000);
```

Agora, se cada aba do site é uma página independente, gerada pelo PHP, você tem duas alternativas:

1 - Ou colocar o script somente na aba home;
2 - Verificar se estamos na Home procurando por um elemento.

Pegue a id de algum elemento que só exista na home do seu site, neste caso a `homeId`. Se esse elemento não existir, faça a função retornar nulo antes de realizar o código. Coloque no começo da função `app.fn`:

```
var homeId = document.getElementById('homeId');
if (homeId == null){

    return;

}
```